# Azure service bus queues troubleshooting techniques

Tags: azure

Can someone provide me with Azure service bus queues troubleshooting techniques. I am a Ops person who supports app on MS Azure.

Thanks and Regards,
Anand

Comment: Anand, Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to describe your issue in more details. Please edit your question and include as much details as possible. As it stands now, the question is very broad and vague and will will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) - it's nice app to administer queues/topics etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Maciej.... but as of now we are using New Relic to administer/monitor service bus. I need help in troubleshooting them functionally.

Comment: Not code level troubleshooting, but functional troubleshooting which would help in creating an KB for the repeating issues.